# Can I add --recurse-submodules to .gitattributes of a git repo?

Tags: git, git-submodules

When working with git repos that use git submodules, people might forget to add `--recurse-submodules` to their git commands or might not think about setting `git config --local submodule.recurse true` locally for a repo. Can I somehow set this by a setting in the repository, e. g. in the `.gitattributes` file?

I just want to make sure that people do not have to think about if a repo contains submodules or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: for technical and security reasons, no *configuration* information is allowed here.  Your best bet is to tell people not to run `git clone` at all: give them some program—such as a shell script—that runs whatever you want *with* whatever *options* you want.

Comment: Could you link or elaborate what (1)technical and (2) security implications there are?